# Ajax IE7 non stop reloading issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I am using AJAX and at the same time executing some javascripts/jquery. I am using .load(). Right now I am having issues on IE7, every browser works fine. Somehow IE7 keeps reloading the same content again and again non stop.

I have tried using

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   cache: false
});
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

None is working.

I really have no idea what is going on and can't find any solutions.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

My AJAX code:

```
$('#ir_content').load(pageurl + ' #ir_inner_content');
```

And because the other file was using a manually coded javascript with backend language so I run the script by using onload on 1 of the img tag:

```
<img src="/images/icon_loadingLarge.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="loading..." id="loading_indicator" style="display: none;" onload="var script_text = $('#webchart_js').html(); eval(script_text);" />
```

script_text:

```
<div id="webchart_js">
    (function($){
      var interactive_chart_config = {
        zoom_historical_default: [% chart_config.chart.chart_interactive.zoom_historical_default %],
        zoom_intraday_default: [% chart_config.chart.chart_interactive.zoom_intraday_default %],
        quotes_delay: [% ir.var.Config.format.quotes_delay %],
        news_on_chart: {
          [% news_types = chart_config.chart.chart_interactive.news_on_chart.keys %]
          [% FOREACH news_type = news_types %]
            [% news_type %]: {
              [% news_options = chart_config.chart.chart_interactive.news_on_chart.${news_type}.keys %]
              [% FOREACH news_option = news_options %]
                [% news_option %]: [% chart_config.chart.chart_interactive.news_on_chart.${news_type}.${news_option} ? 'true' : 'false' %][% IF news_option != news_options.last %],[% END %]
              [% END %]
            }[% IF news_type != news_types.last %],[% END %]
          [% END %]
        },
        modify_news: [
          [% FOREACH news = chart_config.chart.chart_interactive.modify_news.news %]
            {
              [% FOREACH key = news.keys %]
                [% key %]: '[% news.${key} %]'[% IF key != news.keys.last %],[% END %]
              [% END %]
            }[% IF news != chart_config.chart.chart_interactive.modify_news.news.last %],[% END %]
          [% END %]
        ]
      };

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#content_container').web_chart($.extend({}, {
          theme : Highcharts.theme,
          counter_code : "[%= stock_ids.first %]",
          plot_on_load : true,
          always_reload : true,
              loading_indicator_id  : 'loading_indicator',
              chart_setting_id      : 'chart_setting',
              counter_list_form_id  : 'counter_list_form',
              chart_container_id    : 'chart_container',
              css_class_for_flags    : {'N' : 'news_tooltip', 'I' : 'insider_trades_tooltip', 'C' : 'corporate_actions_tooltip'}
        }, interactive_chart_config));
      });
    })(jQuery);

  </div>
```

Comment: What is your ajax code? How do you trigger the load? Give us your code.

Comment: Hi JoDev, thanks for the help. I have inserted my code above, don't know is that sufficient. =x

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `onload` attribute of the image isn't necessary. I think changing your method to an Ajax call like `$.ajax({});` could be usefull. There is probably a piece of code in the `script_text` which trigger somethink.I'm sorry but in your case, I need also the `script_text` content.

Comment: Hi JoDev, I have already input the code above. Btw, do I really need to change to $.ajax({}); ? Because I have a lot of others pages using the same .load() besides this one. =x

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a random string to the end of the ajax URL. This will stop IE caching the content. Like so:

`$('#ir_content').load(pageurl + '?r=' + Math.Random() + '#ir_inner_content');`

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for the help but I have tried that already, it's no use.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to see exactly what is passed and returned from the server?

Comment: Sorry to ask but what is Fiddler? Because when I tried that code, it returns me the whole html page instead of just the content in #ir_inner_content div.

Comment: Fiddler is a a debugging tool that logs all HTTP and optionally HTTPS traffic. See [link](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2)

Comment: Dean: I see. I didn't use that. =x
JoDev: It's the same as Fiddler? Maybe I could try it if it's the same because my company is strict on installing programs. =S

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a web system (no installation) which provide you a coding interface to test your code, and to interact with us. It's not identic to Fiddler!

Answer (score 0):

What `always_reload` is? By passing it to true, is it possible that it's reloading IE7?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#content_container').web_chart($.extend({}, {
          theme : Highcharts.theme,
          counter_code : "[%= stock_ids.first %]",
          plot_on_load : true,
         /*
          * HERE
          */
          always_reload : true,
              loading_indicator_id  : 'loading_indicator',
              chart_setting_id      : 'chart_setting',
              counter_list_form_id  : 'counter_list_form',
              chart_container_id    : 'chart_container',
              css_class_for_flags    : {'N' : 'news_tooltip', 'I' : 'insider_trades_tooltip', 'C' : 'corporate_actions_tooltip'}
        }, interactive_chart_config));
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi JoDev, I have no idea about that too as this is not done by me. But I have tried setting it to false, it's still not working.

Comment: Apparently I have tried putting the var script_text = $('#webchart_js').html(); eval(script_text); into the .load(), the whole thing can't be loaded. So I have no choice but to put into img tag onload. Is there other way that I can do besides putting onload into img tag?

Comment: Where is `#ir_content` regarding to the `<img />`?

Comment: Hi JoDev, sorry for the late response. The #ir_content is outside of the <img />. The structure is #ir_content > #ir_inner_content > <img />. Does that answer your question?